# Render Frames as opposed to AVI?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, file-format

I read a post somewhere that talks about how rendering "frames" is safer than rendering AVI because you won't lose an insane amount of progress if crap happens...

What all does this entail? How can I use this feature, and how can I turn it into a final product (AVI or MP4)?

Thanks in advance!

Ethan

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you render still frames and your process is aborted, already rendered  frames are saved and you can start a new render from a different frame. More advantages are listed in in Blender manual [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/animations.html).

In short, set your output to still format (e.g. JPG, PNG or MultiLayer) and render the animation. Once you are finished with this, use *Video Sequence Editor* in Blender to produce AVI/MP4.

The detailed description includes 15 steps, which are covered in Blender manual [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/animations.html). AVI/MP4 approach is called "Direct approach" there, frames - "Frame sequence approach".

Answer (score 3):

Rendering frames is default behavior.  For example, if you click record animation while an output format like PNG is selected, it will save one PNG per animation frame.  This can protect you from mishaps such as an AVI file growing beyond its 2GB size limit and becoming corrupt.

The sequence of frames can be used as a "video clip" in many video editing packages, including Blender's own Video Sequence Editor.  The frames can be imported there and turned into a finished output file without need to re-render.

Comment: How do I export it from the Video Editor? I can't seem to figure it out. Q_Q

Comment: Check out the [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/animations.html), scroll down to "Frame Sequence Workflow", specifically steps 13 to 15.  Make sure you are using a new scene for this, not the same scene that takes a long time to render.  You essentially "render" the output of the video sequencer to an animation file.  Be sure to select AVI or H.264 as the output type.

Answer (score 0):

To render a series of individual frames rather than an AVI file: select a still image format as the output format (e.g. PNG).

To convert a series of individual frames to an AVI file: use a video editing/conversion utility - personally I use avconv as it can easily take a series of PNG images and produce a video at a requested frame rate.